# How to get the last index of the .txt file and its value?

Tags: java

Don't have the value pre known. `lastIndexOf` hence cannot be used (Since lastIndexOf(WHAT)? WHAT is unknown.

I want to get the last saved value of the file to be compared to a search value. Hence I need the Index of the last value in the file and want to get the value at this last index.

```
public static void searchInFile(double search) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
    try{
    double fl  = Math.floor(search/10000);
    int floor = (int)(fl);
    int key = (int)(search);
    String searchValue = String.valueOf(key);
    String s = null;
    String fname = "TextFile"+(floor+1)+".txt";
    File f = new File(fname);
    do{
    if(f.exists()){
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fname);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            if(s.contains(searchValue)){
                p(""+s.contains(","+searchValue+","));
                p(search+" found in file "+fname);
            }
            else if(s.contains(","+searchValue+",")==false){
                    int last = s.lastIndexOf(s);                    
            }
        }
    }
    else{           
        write(key);
    }
    }while(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "value"? What is in your file? How are you reading it? Where is your code? What have you tried? Read [ask]

Comment: by last saved value you mean last **word** of existing file?

Comment: @holidayCoder. Yes, by last saved value, I mean the last word in the file.

Comment: well then I've posted my code you can try

Comment: and tell me if you need anything to know

Comment: @asteriskNinja Thank you Sir. It did help me and looks like I'm close to the desired results. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @kanika you can upvote and accept if you think it works

Comment: @asteriskNinja I'd love to upvote and accept sir, But i don't have that privilege yet.

Comment: then you can accept it, as you asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure If You are looking for the index of last word in `.txt file` If you do, then this might help .

```
public static void checkIndex() {
            File file = new File("path");
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String strReading = "";
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while ((strReading = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(strReading);
                }
                int index = buffer.toString().lastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
                System.out.println(buffer.substring(index));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I could understand is only that you have multiple index files in which you have to search a value. but what do you means by "Last Index of". The problem is not clear very well. even the logic of your program is not explainable enough to catch the problem meaning very well.

Could you please update the problem statement and share your snippet in more details so that people can understand this and answer.